# skype crashes, also audio problems 13.10

Tags: 13.10, skype

Ive always had problems with skype ususally with audio, trying to keep the usb headphones set correctly.  Wha tive found is that when i see the Pulseaudio server in the audio list in Skype, and thats my only option, Skype works good,...stable and reliable.
Second issue:  Its been crashing a bit, just locks up and the only thing to free it up is a reboot,..
These problems are under the new release 13.10. so concider this a bug report.
DEVELOPERS:  You all need to make a good channel for people to report bugs,....
OK thats all/

Comment: Skype is not part of Ubuntu. It's a third-party application for which you can ask support for at the vendor - Microsoft. And secondly, this is not the right place for bug reports about Ubuntu either way. Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with skype since 12.10 and I don't know why they haven't fixed this yet.
The problem is with a dependency library which contains plugins for distributing audio through the system.
Try to run skype through terminal and if you get this common error:

```
xxxxx@UX31A-13:~$ skype
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

then this is the solution

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
```