# Skype freeze when trying to realize a call

Tags: skype

I've installed Skype and it appears to work fine right up until the point where I try to call someone. If I try to video call someone then the program freezes and I have to force quit. I've tried several 'solutions' I've found on various forums but none seem to work. Now, when I try to call the Echo service as a test to see if the bug's fixed, it seems to connect and start the non-video call, except that it's completely silent. No audio at all.

Comment: Naturalis's answer on this question fixed the problems for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362717/skype-crashes-also-audio-problems-13-10

Answer (score 7):

This should make a permanent change for the workaround:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype %U/' /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

Thanks go [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html)

**If you are using KDE:**

Another non-terminal way is to to right-click on start button and select "Edit applications...":

[image]

NOTE: If you are using KDE session restoring (System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Session Management -> On login: Restore previous session) then after system restart (or login) Skype will not catch `PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC` environment variable until you restart it via its `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10  sound interrupts badly. But suggesting to reinstall from Software Centre or from Skype download page did not help.

But running this from command line solved the problem:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 /usr/bin/skype
```

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks! Anyone able to explain why this works?

Comment: Is there any way that this could be made to work from the unity launcher?

Comment: It works on Linux Mint 16 too!

Comment: [Reinstalling Skype from Canonical Partner repos](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html) did not help you if you start Skype via anything that bypasses the (patched) skype.desktop file. For example, starting via the Alt+F2 mini-terminal. To apply your solution there also, create an executable file `/usr/local/bin/skype` with first line `#!/bin/bash` and next line `env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 /usr/bin/skype`

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for Skype on 13.10. I installed again and started to work. Check it out: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Same as answer by @warwaruk.